# Can't connect to remote node (GUI)

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, connection

I have tried using the 64 bit GUI wallet for Linux on a few different distros (Ubuntu, Debian), with no success. The blockchain doesn't sync.

This is what the terminal looks like whenever I hit "Connect"

```
2018-03-02 18:00:16.658     7fb961d6f700    ERROR   default src/wallet/api/utils.cpp:46 error: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)
2018-03-02 18:00:16.672     7fb961d6f700    DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:184   Some problems at connect, message: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)
2018-03-02 18:00:18.816     7fb961d6f700    ERROR   default src/wallet/api/utils.cpp:46 error: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)
2018-03-02 18:00:18.818     7fb961d6f700    DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:184   Some problems at connect, message: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)


2018-03-02 18:00:51.517     7fb9433b9700    TRACE   WalletAPI   src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:1292  refreshThreadFunc: waiting for refresh...
2018-03-02 18:00:51.519     7fb961d6f700    DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:184   Some problems at connect, message: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)
2018-03-02 18:01:01.517     7fb9433b9700    TRACE   WalletAPI   src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:1302  refreshThreadFunc: refresh lock acquired...
2018-03-02 18:01:01.517     7fb9433b9700    TRACE   WalletAPI   src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:1303  refreshThreadFunc: m_refreshEnabled: 1
2018-03-02 18:01:01.517     7fb9433b9700    TRACE   WalletAPI   src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:1304  refreshThreadFunc: m_status: 0
2018-03-02 18:01:01.517     7fb9433b9700    TRACE   WalletAPI   src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:1306  refreshThreadFunc: refreshing...
2018-03-02 18:01:01.519     7fb9433b9700    DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:184   Some problems at connect, message: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)
2018-03-02 18:01:01.519     7fb9433b9700    TRACE   WalletAPI   src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:1332  doRefresh: skipping refresh - daemon is not synced
2018-03-02 18:01:01.519     7fb9433b9700    TRACE   WalletAPI   src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:1292  refreshThreadFunc: waiting for refresh...
2018-03-02 18:01:01.521     7fb961d6f700    DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:184   Some problems at connect, message: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)
```

I have tried several different nodes from https://moneroworld.com/ and none work.

Comment: If you start `monerod` w/ `./monerod` does it get stuck on `1/1` (you can check by typing `status` into the `monerod` terminal)? If so, it's probably a local network issue and not a Monero issue. Your logs from connecting to the remote node also kind of indicate this.